# Aggregate in an Array MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I would like to aggregate $match on the data inside the array object:

```
{ example: [{target: "1"}] }
```

I have tried `$match`, `$elemMatch`, `$arrayEleAt` but I dont know how to write the correct syntax.

```
{ $lookup: { from: "example", localField: "user_id", foreignField: "user_id", as: "example" } },

    {
        $match: {
            "start_date": { $gte: new Date(startDate) },
            "end_date": { $lte: new Date(endDate) },
            "type": Type,
            "target": "1"

        },
    },

    { $sort: { startDate: 1 } },
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write it like this:

```
{
    $match: {
        "start_date": { $gte: new Date(startDate) },
        "end_date": { $lte: new Date(endDate) },
        "type": Type,
        "example.target": "1"

    },
},
```

Comment: Yes, I found out thank you. But I added $unwind able to match this way because lookup inserts object into an Array.

{ $lookup: { from: "example", localField: "user_id", foreignField: "user_id", as: "example" } },
{ $unwind: "$example" },

{
    $match: {
        "start_date": { $gte: new Date(startDate) },
        "end_date": { $lte: new Date(endDate) },
        "type": Type,
        "example.target": "1"

    },
},

Comment: so it works for you?, if not edit your question to match your full query and ill try to help.

Comment: Yes, thank you Tom, it does. I have had to use $unwind to remove the array. Thank you.